# Conversion of hCard (Microformats) to Schema.org (JSON-LD)

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, microformats

I'm trying to convert my hCard (Microformats) to the Schema.org equivalent (using JSON-LD), but getting lost in semantics. We are a local taxi business / professional service.

```html
<div id="taxis" class="vcard">
<span class="fn n"><span class="additional-name">Jack</span> &amp; <span class="given-name">Jill</span> <span class="family-name">Badders</span></span>
<div class="fn org">CC Taxis</div>
  <a class="email" href="cctaxis@gmail.com"</a>
 <div class="adr">
    <span class="street-address">The Farm</span>,
    <span class="locality">Dingly Dell</span>,
    <span class="region">GLOS</span>.
    <span class="postal-code">GL23 5TY</span>
    <span class="country-name">United Kingdom</span>
 </div>
 <span class="geo">
    <span class="latitude"><span class="value-title" title="32.0507074436492"></span></span>
    <span class="longitude"><span class="value-title" title="-11.7807292938232422"></span></span>
 </span>
Phone: <span class="tel">01234 567890</span>
<p><a href="http://www.cctaxis.com">www.cctaxis.com</a></p></div>
```

I've got so far, but not too sure where to add the contact information for Jack and Jill?

Do I need to add Organization to the schema as well?

```html
<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
  "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "name": "CCTaxis",
  "url": "www.cctaxis.com",
  "logo": "logo.jpg",
  "image": "image.jpg",
  "description": "My local taxi business and country tours",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "The Farm",
    "addressLocality": "Dingly Dell",
    "addressRegion": "GLOS",
    "postalCode": "GL23 5TY",
    "addressCountry": "United Kingdom"
  },
  "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": "32.0507074436492",
    "longitude": "11.7807292938232422"
  },
  "hasMap": "My Google map ref.",
  "contactPoint": {
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "contactType": "email contact type",
    "telephone": "+44 1234 567890"
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Note that in the first snippet you are not using Microdata nor Schema.org; you are using Microformats. (I edited your question.)